# How to link against static library with numpy + gfortran

Tags: numpy, openmp, gfortran, f2py

I use numpy to create a module made of fortran 90 code on Windows with MSVC and gfortran. The idea is to create a wheel with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

I use the following python code to create the module. Everything compiles, runs fine, till I use gfortran libraries like openmp (`-lgomp`). I manage to create objects with `-fopenmp`, but fail to link.

When I link against against `gomp`, I don't know where to give this input. The compilation flag `-fopenmp` goes in `extra_f90_compile_args`, but . I have tried several arguments without success (`extra_link_args`, `library_dirs`, `libraries`, `runtime_library_dirs`, `extra_objects`, `f2py_options`).

I have found a solution by editing the function that generates the link command for gfortran.
If I edit the following file `numpy\distutils\fcompiler\gnu.py`, I can add `-lgomp`, it works, but it is dirty since I modify numpy.

How can I give this extra gfortran link library (`-lgomp`)?

```
import platform
import setuptools
import numpy
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration


def configuration_openmp(parent_package='', top_path=None):
    config = Configuration('mymodule', parent_package, top_path)
    config.add_extension('mymodule',
                         sources=['mymodule/mymodule.f90'],
                         include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
                         extra_f90_compile_args=['-g0', '-O3', '-fopenmp'],
                         )
    config.make_config_py()
    return config
metadata = dict(configuration=configuration_openmp)

setup(**metadata)
```

Here is the fortran code

```
module mod
    subroutine test_openmp()
        use omp_lib
        write(6,*) omp_get_num_procs()
        write(6,*) omp_get_num_threads()
    end subroutine
end module mod
```

Here is the link error

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mymodule\mymodule.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.7\mymodule\seama
s_integrate-f2pywrappers2.o -LC:\MinGW\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2 -L"C:\Program Files\Python37\libs" -L"C:\Program Files\Python37\PCbuild\amd64" -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\.libs\libseam
as_i.CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.gfortran-win_amd64.dll -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--output-def,build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libmymodule_i.CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.gfortran-win
_amd64.def -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -static -mlong-double-64
build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mymodule\mymodule.o:mymodule.f90:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_procs_'
build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mymodule\mymodule.o:mymodule.f90:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads_'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mymodule\mymodule.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pda
ta'
```

Maybe solution is to directly use f2py

```
f2py -m demo --fcompiler=gfortran --f90flags='-O3 -fopenmp' -lgomp -c test.f90
```

Comment: Normally, you don't need to explicitly link with libgomp, but you need `-fopenmp` both at compile **and** link time.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for the comment. The problem is how to give `-fopenmp` or `-lgomp` to gfortran linker.